# Map with custom value object

Tags: java

I want to have a Map object to contain specific value types.

```
Map<String,Object> foo = new HashMap<String,Object>();
foo.put("1",new Integer(1));
foo.put("2", new String("hello"):
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : foo.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
    //do something
    }
   else if(entry.getValue() instanceof Double) {
       //throw Exception
    }
}
```

You can see what i am trying to accomplish. I need specific Value types in my Map object so i don't have to put lots of if/else statements. How do i accomplish this ?

Comment: Then you would have create different maps for each of them.. You cannot put `Integer` and `String` in the same Map without generalizing the map to be of type `Object`.

Comment: Use several maps. Or use an interface which is common to all the value types. Note that `new String("hello")` doesn't make much sense. Just use "hello".

Comment: You could use a `case` statement...

Comment: Actually, it's not clear what you're trying to do, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the specific type provided in the value object for a map so i can convert it the way i want to send the response to Y destination which expects that conversion.

Comment: somekittens: you cannot use switch statements on an object whose type is unkown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like the idea of having multiple maps, you can use the nice OOP feature called *overriding*.
see [Override Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) for more information.

I would probably use *composition* pattern to wrap the value types and then define a interface for the action depending of the value types.

```
public abstract class ValueType {

    public abstract void valueSpecificAction(); 
}

public class DoubleValueType extends ValueType {

    private Double value;

    public DoubleValueType(Double value) {
            this.value = value;
    }

    public void valueSpecificAction() {
        //do double specific actions
    }
}

public class StringValueType extends ValueType {

    private String value;


    public void valueSpecificAction() {
        //do string specific actions


     }   
}
```

You can then add the objects of type **ValueType** in the maps.

```
Map<String,ValueType> foo = new HashMap<String,ValueType>();
foo.put("key1", new DoubleValueType(42.0));
```

later you can get the value, which has the type ValueType with the public method *valueSpecificAction()* which do the stuff depending on the specific type.

Comment: What is a "overwrite method"? Do you mean overriding?

Comment: ah you are right, I will edit this in the post with right orthography

Comment: This will eliminate them for atleast the data types which cannot be inserted in the map. Thanks. Quick question. Since i am using no library i was curious to see how should i handle the Date Object, Datetime and time object classes ?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can avoid to have an if-else somewhere in general.

Jan's solution would spare you the if-else only if the value types can be determine at compulation-time. That is the case in the toy example above but is it so in your actual problem?

If it is a matter of making the code look cleaner you can always hide the if-else and conversions in a set of private methods.